# how to make a button pressed by default in html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

There I have a button that is hidden from the user but want it to be clicked by default like with a check box if you want it to be checked by default you add the checked attribute is there any way you could do the same thing with a button here is my code

```
<input id="submit" type="hidden" value="Reverse Geocode" autofocus>
```

Comment: what you want? If user clicked the check box button should be clicked??

Comment: you can just call the `click event` of the button `window.load()` or if you have a function assigned to it just call it.

Comment: That is not a button, but hidden field.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think <input name="submit" type="hidden" value="Reverse Geocode"> is what you are looking for. If it's not then why not just use onload event to trigger something?

Comment: What is your goal actually? You are asking about button which is "clicked" by default, but your html shows an hidden input field.

Answer (score 7):

You can do as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submit").click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can do the following:

```js
document.getElementById('chkTest').addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(this.checked)
    document.getElementById('submit').click();
});

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('button clicked');
});
```

```html
<input id="submit" type="hidden" value="Reverse Geocode" autofocus />

<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" /> Check To Click The Button
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, your button is not a button. It's a a hidden field.

In order to make it a button, change `type="hidden"` to `type="button"`. To make it invisible to the user, you could use inline styles like this: `style="display: none;"`.

As a result, your button looks like this: 
`<input id="submit" style="display: none" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">`

---

Now, to click it, simply call the `click()` method:

```
document.getElementById('submit').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Trigger click event on the button as soon as document is ready.You have to write the click event as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#yourButtonId")[0].click();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now i understand your question, You want default click in your submit button. Try click event, It will trigger the submit.

```
<script>
   $('#submit').trigger('click');
</script>
```

> In JavaScript

```
   document.getElementById("submit").click();
```